# Update record in the xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

This way I can get the details of the record and I want to know how can i edit the values and update it to the same record??

How can I check for unique values in the attribute??

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filePath);

string id = textBox6.Text;
XElement element = doc.Descendants("Customer").FirstOrDefault(p => p.Attribute("id").Value == id);

if (element != null)
{
    //found
    textBox6.Text = textBox6.Text;
    textBox1.Text = (string)element.Element("FirstName");
    textBox2.Text = (string)element.Element("LastName"); 
    textBox3.Text = (string)element.Element("Mobile");
    textBox4.Text = (string)element.Element("Address");
    textBox5.Text = (string)element.Element("Country");
}
```

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CustomerRecord>
  <Customer id="43543543">
    <FirstName>sdf</FirstName>
    <LastName>fdsf</LastName>
    <Mobile>23452345é</Mobile>
    <Address>zfdsf</Address>
    <Country>dsfdsf</Country>
  </Customer>
</CustomerRecord>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XElement element;
XDocument doc;

private void Load()
{
    doc = XDocument.Load(filePath);

    string id = textBox6.Text;
    element = doc.Descendants("Customer").FirstOrDefault(p => p.Attribute("id").Value == id);

    if (element != null)
    {
        //found
        textBox6.Text = textBox6.Text;
        textBox1.Text = (string)element.Element("FirstName");
        textBox2.Text = (string)element.Element("LastName"); 
        textBox3.Text = (string)element.Element("Mobile");
        textBox4.Text = (string)element.Element("Address");
        textBox5.Text = (string)element.Element("Country");
    }
}

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    element.Attribute("id").Value = textBoxID.text;
    var firstNameSimilarElement = doc.Descendants("FirstName").FirstOrDefault(fn => fn.Value == textBox1.Text)
    if (firstNameSimilarElement != null && firstNameSimilarElement.Parent != element)
    {
         MessageBox.Show("First Name already exists");
    }
    else
    {
        element.Element("FirstName").Value = textBox1.Text;
    }
    // Same for all fields
    doc.Save(filePath);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Example I use only 2 child nodes (FirstName,LastName). and I took file.xml in same directory with exe file, here's the code :

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;

namespace UpdateXmlRecord
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private XmlDocument xDoc;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xDoc.Load("file.xml");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieve Xml Node
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string id = txtId.Text;
            string fName = "", lName = "";
            foreach (XmlElement element in xDoc.DocumentElement)
            {
                if (element.Name == "Customer" && element.Attributes["id"].Value == id)
                {
                    foreach (XmlNode node in element)
                    {
                        if (node.Name == "FirstName")
                        {
                            fName = node.InnerText;
                        }

                        if (node.Name == "LastName")
                        {
                            lName = node.InnerText;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            txtFName.Text = fName;
            txtLName.Text = lName;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Save Xml Node With Custom Value
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string id = txtId.Text;
            foreach (XmlElement element in xDoc.DocumentElement)
            {
                if (element.Name == "Customer" && element.Attributes["id"].Value == id)
                {
                    foreach (XmlNode node in element)
                    {
                        if (node.Name == "FirstName")
                        {
                            node.InnerText = txtFName.Text;
                        }

                        if (node.Name == "LastName")
                        {
                            node.InnerText = txtLName.Text;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            xDoc.Save("file.xml");
        }
    }
}
```

hope it's helpfull, enjoy it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can hash the contents of the node and append the hash to the resulting XML. The hash will be unique enoughto act as a 'primary key' to your record.

Comment: :Please explain me more in detail.

Comment: It looks to me you're trying to 'generate' some sort of ID value to get a unique handle (id) to your record, based on the uniqueness of the contents of this record. If you would just conatenate all the customer's fields together (in a string) and call the 'GetHashCode()' on the resulting string, you would get a number acting as some sort of primary key (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.gethashcode.aspx). Ofcourse this number is not ultimately unique, but if will narrow down your result set. From there, do a field-by-field compare to narrow down to your unique record.